# What is the syntax to find a value in an array of objects by a property?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

What is the syntax to find a value in an array object?

```js
var pStData = [];

pStData.push({ st: 'WV', geom: 'xxx' });
pStData.push({ st: 'TX', geom: 'yyy' });

var sGeom = pStData.find(pStData => pStData.st == 'TX').geom;

console.log(sGeom);
```

In my code, `pStData.find(pStData => pStData.st == 'TX')` is `undefined`.

Comment: There is zero jQuery in your code. It also works as expected.

Comment: sorry, i did not say jQuery is in my code. I am asking for a jQuery solution.

Comment: You don't need a jQuery solution if you create the array correctly... You're looking for a sledgehammer to crack a walnut. If you really want a jQuery solution, look up $.each

Comment: @DougMoore The problem you’re describing, any sensible solution, and your code are all completely unrelated to jQuery and _should_ contain no jQuery. You’re working with basic JavaScript here. You’re asking for JavaScript solutions.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+find+value+in+array+of+objects+by+property) of [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7364150/4642212). Your code works as-is. There is no issue.

Comment: ok it looks like my variable call into the index had an extra space, so when I .trim() it started working in all versions posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than no jQuery there at all, you're defining the array as an array of objects. Define an object like this:

```
var pStData = {};
pStData['WV'] = {geom: 'xxx'};
pStData['TX'] = {geom: 'yyy'};
```

Then you can access simply by

```
var sGeom = pStData['WV'].geom;
```

You can also access it via

```
var sGeom = pStData.WV.geom;
```

Of course you don't need to define the object if you're only looking up a string value, for example this would work just as well.

```
var pStData = {};
pStData['WV'] = 'xxx';
pStData['TX'] = 'yyy';
```

However, defining it as an object does future proof your code, should you need to add extra data values later. Never be afraid to do a bit of future proofing, it can save a lot of work later.

Comment: @DougMoore You’re not using the `{ geom: "`…`" }` objects.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

```
 function findObjectInArrayByProperty(array, propertyName, propertyValue) {
      return array.find((o) => { return o[propertyName] === propertyValue });
 }
```

So, in your case:

```js
function findObjectInArrayByProperty(array, propertyName, propertyValue) {
      return array.find((o) => { return o[propertyName] === propertyValue });
 }
     var pStData = [];
     pStData.push({ st: 'WV', geom: 'xxx' });
     pStData.push({ st: 'TX', geom: 'yyy' });
     var resultObj = findObjectInArrayByProperty(pStData, "st", "TX");
     
     console.log(resultObj);
```

output -> { st: 'TX', geom: 'yyy' }